# Popup images in Excel

Tags: excel-2016

Formerly you could add images to comments as popup:

See: 
[Click here](http://www.perrinator.com/the-trick-to-inserting-an-image-in-a-specific-cell-without-the-need-for-macro-excel-2013/)

In 2016 the comments has changed, see image below:

[image]

Is there anyway to create a popup with a given image in Excel 2016?